# Initialize map inside a map in groovy

Tags: groovy, hashmap

How can I initialize a map with following structure 
`["id":["Margin":["Count":long-value,"Avg":double-value]]]` 
in groovy.

Comment: Just the way you've written it! Just replace `long-value` and `double-value` with valid variables or constants.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
def myMapInsideMap = [id:[Margin:[Count:longValue,Avg:doubleValue]]]
```

Comment: keys in maps are Strings by default. Map can trim down to: `[ id : [Margin : [Count : 100, Avg: 30.00 ] ] ]`